# Not able to compile PJSIP on Ubuntu for Blackberry 10

Tags: blackberry-10, pjsip

I am trying to compile PJSIP on Ubuntu according to this document:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Porting-PJSIP-PJMEDIA-and-PJLIB-to-BlackBerry-10/ta-p/2085751

When I am executing this command: `./buildpjsip` (it's on number 8 in document), it is showing these errors:

```
cp: cannot create regular file /x86/lib': No such file or directory
/home/ahsish/bb10-pjsipdemo-master/pjbuildscripts/pjsip-build /home/ahsish/bb10-pjsipdemo-master/pjbuildscripts
/home/ahsish/bb10-pjsipdemo-master/pjbuildscripts/pjsip-build/trunk /home/ahsish/bb10-pjsipdemo-master/pjbuildscripts/pjsip-build /home/ahsish/bb10-pjsipdemo-master/pjbuildscripts
Makefile:1: build.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:2: build/host-.mak: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `build/host-.mak'.  Stop.
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0
checking target system type... i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0
checking for i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
aconfigure: error: in `/home/ahsish/bb10-pjsipdemo-master/pjbuildscripts/pjsip-build/trunk':
aconfigure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
Makefile:1: build.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:2: build/host-.mak: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `build/host-.mak'.  Stop.
Makefile:1: build.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:2: build/host-.mak: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `build/host-.mak'.  Stop.
/home/ahsish/bb10-pjsipdemo-master/pjbuildscripts/pjsip-build /home/ahsish/bb10-pjsipdemo-master/pjbuildscripts
adding: libopencore-amrwb.a (deflated 67%) adding: libopencore-amrnb.a (deflated 70%)
/home/ahsish/bb10-pjsipdemo-master/pjbuildscripts*
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the issue before and solved it successfully. I think what results in the issue is that, after you executed the step 4 in the document: ***Execute bbndk-env.bat or bbndk-env.sh from the root of your installation of the Native SDK*.** You shouldn't close the command prompt or open a new terminal. I mean you should execute the rest steps in the same terminal, then you will build the library successfully. Also, you had better ensure your gcc is the newest version. Good luck for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try first:

- $ cd bb10-pjsipdemo/pjbuildscripts/pjsip-checkout/trunk
- $ ./configure
- $ touch pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h
- $ make dep
- $ make

Reference: http://www.pjsip.org/pjlib/docs/html/pjlib_build_sys_pg.htm

And then run bb10-pjsipdemo/pjbuildscripts/buildpjsip